# How do I make a d3.js visualisation update when the data changes?

Tags: javascript, python, d3.js

I've got a visualisation based on [D3.js forced directed layout](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045). The data that's driving it is in a database.

Currently have a python script to pull the data from the database, reformat it in JSON format and then save it off in a file which D3 looks at. (it can take ~60 seconds for the query to run)

I wanted to extend it to have an input control on the same page as the graph, so a user can enter a user-id and then get the network relating to that user. The webpage would pass the userid to the python script which would then print out the file and the graph would update without having to reload the page.

Any suggestions on how to set this up? Could I set up a text form that executes a cgi script without leaving the page?

Comment: It sounds like all you need is another call to `d3.json` with the appropriate ID in the URL to get new data and update it.

Comment: What would call this? After you type in the userid and press enter, the python script will start running. Then after a few minutes the data will land in the json file. How will the d3 know when to call the update?

Comment: It doesn't. You have to tell it.